# Access to Google Cloud Datalab Fails with ssh Error

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Trying to access Google Cloud Datalab server with: 
docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "${HOME}:/content" -e
"GATEWAY_VM=mltensorflow-1470671201129/us-east1-b/vm-instance-name"  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local

as per [Run Cloud Datalab on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce)

It fails with: 
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH to the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

I am on a Windows 10 client.
Repeated installation now produces this error:
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
Failed to set up the SSH tunnel to the VM vm-instance-name

Instance is accessible via other means, for example:
gcloud compute --project "project_name" ssh --zone "us-west1-a" "ins-name"

Comment: Just a quick check.  Did you replace `vm-instance-name` with the vm instance you created? The reason I ask is because `vm-instance-name` does not match the instance name used in  `gcloud compute ...`

Comment: Good catch, Anthonios. Unfortunately, that is not the cause ( I listed generic gcloud statement - real arguments are ok and match actual vm instance name ).

Comment: I think something is missing in Datalab docs - they just changed way you access it over the weekend. It might be something along the lines of: gloud docker

Comment: I ran through the docs and I could connect to a gateway server in GCE. Note: I received the same error that you mention here (`Failed to setup the SSH tunnel`). After 30 seconds, I tried `docker run it ...` again and didn't get the error.

Comment: Repeated execution didn't work for me. Are you on Windows ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not on Windows. Docker doesn't work in my windows virtual machine. From https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-use-docker-inside-virtual-machine-with-windows-server-2016/19739 , "Docker for Windows requires hyper-v and virtualization extensions. Without nested virtualization (not available in VirtualBox), Docker for Windows can't install and work."

Comment: I got passed that point - it is simple to enable Hyper-V and Docker works on Windows. 
It is just that geniuses from GOOG Dloud Datalab didn't produce working docker container on Windows. So I switched to Ubuntu as per below, got passed docker run command, but am now having a problem with empty notebook page.

Comment: I'm experencing the same issue. Could it be an authentication problem? I get the following message warning after the authentication step.'WARNING: `gcloud auth login` will stop writing application default credentials
in a future release. See:
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#toolcloudsdk
for more information.'

Comment: This is all quite annoying. GOOG had working Datalab, and now switched to junk. How are we supposed to trust GOOG public cloud if they pull the rug from under us ?

Comment: @RankoMosic `I got passed that point` -> The issue I have is specific to running Docker for Windows inside of a Windows virtual machine using Virtualbox which doesn't support nested virtualization. I don't believe there is a solution for that. Docker for Windows works when you have a Windows host. Can you confirm you are using a windows host?

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on Ubuntu. I want to make sure that we are both using the same docker image. Can you run `docker pull gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local` ?

Comment: @RankoMosic Can you create an issue [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/new)  with the full console output? My configuration works great in Ubuntu, and I want to help, but I need more information. I appreciate your patience while we work through the issue.

Comment: @PeterCoghill `I'm experencing the same issue. ` -> Can you create an issue [here](http://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/new)  with the full console output? Please describe your issue in as much detail as possible.

Comment: I created an issue on github.

Comment: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/pull/951) which appears to resolve the 'blank page' issue. In the meantime, there is a temporary workaround documented in the comments in [Datalab Github Issue #950](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/950).

Answer (score 2):

The command docker run ... has an argument that doesn't work on Windows AFAIK. But the strange thing is that I would expect a very different error and in fact managed to get an error due to ${HOME}.

Here is the command I ran and it worked well - after substituting the value for HOME (you will need to replace [proj-id] below.

```
docker run -it -p "8081:8080" -v "/C/Users/dinesh/Documents/:/content"    -e "GATEWAY_VM=[proj-id]/us-central1-f/datalab"  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
```

Not sure if this will work for you but something worth trying in case substitution was a problem. (I am assuming that the VM was created with datalab-gateway.yaml without any errors.)

Thanks.

Dinesh Kulkarni

PM, Datalab & Cloud ML

Comment: Hardcoding path as per above didn't work ( path related error was popping out initially, then disappeared after a while; that's why I didn't bother hardcoding it ).

Comment: Repeated the whole process, now on Ubuntu 16.04. Got passed the above problem point.
Ran into another problem:
Browser is not showing any Python notebooks.

Comment: Please could you provide more information to help troubleshoot? What do you see in the browser?

Comment: When I point to localhost:8081 URL changes to
localhost:8081/tree/datalab and blank screen is displayed. 
No notebooks are loaded. 
( I did get past "Allow" button ).

Comment: This could be why - found this line in docker run ... output:
{"name":"app","hostname":"326a7fabf546","pid":181,"level":50,"err":{"message":"timeout","name":"Error","stack":"Error: timeout\n    at timeoutFunc (/datalab/web/node_modules/tcp-port-used/index.js:192:25)\n    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)"},"msg":"Failed to start Jupyter server for user anonymous.","time":"2016-08-17T09:25:32.252Z","v":0}

Comment: @RankoMosic One possibility is that a local firewall is blocking the connection.  Did you by any chance make firewall configurations in ubuntu (such as `iptables`), which could be blocking local connections (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: iptables is not running

Answer (score 1):

The problem with official instructions [Run Cloud Datalab on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce), is that provided command to create the gateway VM does not work correctly on Windows.

Replace `--metadata "google-container-manifest=$(cat datalab-gateway.yaml)"` with `--metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=datalab-gateway.yaml` and it will create VM with datalab-gateway.yaml without any errors. You can login to your new instance and run `sudo docker ps` to double check if container is running.

Afterwards you can continue with next step (`docker run...`), just substitute  `${HOME}` with `/C/Users/<your path>` as Dinesh described.